# identify mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql

I've write a web-application in PHP which has 30 tables+views. From time to time my application doesn't work and think this is related to the mysql db.

Unfortunately  I can't see the errors from the browser on that server because php.ini says so. Also when I try to connect to mysql db using phpMyAdmin the connection fails when I try to select my DB.

How can i see which is the problem to my mysql DB. It works from time to time but I don't understand why.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look in the MySQL error log - it's under `/var/log/mysqld.log` on my setup...

Your PHP errors may be getting sent to another log file - try the Apache / IIS error log (global or for the particular vhost, depending on your config for Apache - I can't say for IIS) or to the system log - `/var/log/messages`